# How to add custom keyboard app in iOS device setting menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have devloped custom keyboard App for iOS device. I want to add this keyboard  application's to iphone device setting menu to add new keyboard.  When I install my app in device it isn't shown in setting menu to add new keyboard.

Comment: What steps have you taken?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode if you go to File > New > Target... then iOS > Application Extension > Custom Keyboard and create the target, then the next time you install the app you will see your keyboard in the list of keyboards to add, in settings. You have to subclass UIInputViewController to handle the UI of the keyboard; this subclass will be instantiated once every time the keyboard appears. Creating the target makes a default subclass for you.

This is currently the only way to make a keyboard that can be installed from settings for use in other apps.